A trajectory nearby a stable focus - FitzHugh-Nagumo model
I made a Python code to an adapted FitzHugh-Nagumo model
\begin{align}\label{system}
    \dfrac{du}{dt}&= -Gu\left(1-\dfrac{u}{u_{th}}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{u}{u_p}\right) - \eta_1uw,\\
    \dfrac{dw}{dt}&= \eta_2\left(\dfrac{u}{u_p} - \eta_3 w\right).
\end{align}
The code is available in https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MTATBbzGoHfRnXOmKWSwkd_nW4JRs8-V?usp=sharing.
The parameters are $G, \eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3, u_{th}, u_p = 1.704,4.4,0.024,1,13,100$.
If it is okay, $(w,u)=(0.5637002119,56.37002119)$ is an equilibrium, and we have

Jacobian trace $−0.00479222837163327$
Jacobian eigenvalues $[-0.00239611+0.24302266i, -0.00239611-0.24302266i]$

So, the point is a stable focus (spiral).
But how can the trajectory pass nearby a stable focus without being sucked into it?

Thank you for any clarification.

@Moo It is done, thank you for your attention.

I ,the current, and the other constants, are not necessary to the question, I'll delete they. Thank you! @Moo

@Moo yes, I am worried about the last one.

@Moo I double checked the equations, I think it's ok. The phase portrait is the last figure, can you see it?
